# Switching to mongoose 4.0 filters out most properties on save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the below `schema`:

```
{ district: { type: Number, min: 0 },
  endDate: { type: Date },
  miniRouteIndex: { type: Number, min: 0 },
  miniRouteIndexAltName: { type: String },
  startDate: { type: Date },
  mco: { type: String, match: /^\d{3}$/ },
  route: { type: String, match: /^\d{6}$/ },
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  standardPlan: { type: String },
  storageStrategy: { type: String },
  trafficNote: 
   { timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
     message: { type: String } },
  uBoxStrategy: { type: String },
  uMoveStrategy: { type: String },
  dealers: 
   [ { dealerId: { match: /^\d{6}$/, type: String },
       dealerIndex: { type: Number },
       prospects: 
        [ { birminghamPlanFixedId: { type: Number },
            entityIndex: { type: Number },
            nonBirminghamPlanId: { type: Number } } ] } ] }
```

I perform the following operations on it:

```
var mongooseSchema = new mongoose.Schema(schema, model.options)
models[_.camelCase(model.name)] = mongoose.model(model.name, mongooseSchema)
```

When I attempt to `save` a document I get the following in the database:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("557215714f79f7f41088caf5"),
  "dealers" : [ ], 
  "trafficNote" : {
      "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-06-05T21:32:33.801Z")
  },
  "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-06-05T21:32:33.799Z"),
  "__v" : 0
}
```

It has pretty much completely filtered out all my properties. What am I doing wrong? The migration didn't say anything about this. There was a switch from `type` to `kind` but that was for errors.

**Update**

Test code for posting data:

```
{
    "miniRouteIndex": 0,
    "dealers": [
        {
            "dealerIndex": 0,
            "dealerId": "000000",
            "prospects": []
        },
        {
            "dealerIndex": 1,
            "dealerId": "000001",
            "prospects": [
                {
                    "entityIndex": 0,
                    "birminghamPlanFixedId": 1234567,
                    "nonBirminghamPlanId": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "dealerIndex": 3,
            "dealerId": "000002",
            "prospects": [
                {
                    "birminghamPlanFixedId": 0123456,
                    "entityIndex": 0,
                    "nonBirminghamPlanId": 0
                },
                {
                    "birminghamPlanFixedId": 2345678,
                    "entityIndex": 1,
                    "nonBirminghamPlanId": 123456
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "district": 0,
    "timestamp": "4/20/2015 2:30:25 AM",
    "mco": "000",
    "miniRouteIndexAltName": "routeName",
    "route": "000003",
    "standardPlan": "none",
    "storageStrategy": "none",
    "trafficNote": {
        "message": "Test- Let me know when you see this. Sabrina",
        "timestamp": "Mon Apr 20 2015 16:24:03 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)"
    },
    "uBoxStrategy": "none",
    "uMoveStrategy": "none",
    "startDate": "Mon Apr 20 2015 16:24:03 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)",
    "endDate": "Mon Apr 20 2015 16:24:03 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)"
}
```

**Code that saves the plan**:

```
var post = (miniRoutePlans: MiniRoutePlan[]): Q.Promise<string[]> =>
    q.all(
        miniRoutePlans.map(plan => q.ninvoke(new db.miniRoute(plan), 'save'))
    )
    .then((result: any[]) =>
            _(result)
            .flatten()
            .map((o: any) => _.isObject(o)? o._id: null)
            .compact()
            .value()
    )
```

**And as plain JavaScript**:

```
var db = require('../../models/models');
var q = require('q');
var _ = require('lodash');
var post = function (miniRoutePlans) {
    return q.all(miniRoutePlans.map(function (plan) { return q.ninvoke(new db.miniRoute(plan), 'save'); }))
        .then(function (result) {
        return _(result)
            .flatten()
            .map(function (o) { return _.isObject(o) ? o._id : null; })
            .compact()
            .value();
    });
};
module.exports = post;
```

Comment: I'll have access to it when I get to work on Monday. Sorry for the slowness! It is the same code that I used under Mongoose 3.8.xx.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, Added the code you asked for and fixed the schema. The reason I did an object dump is because I generate the schema from TypeScript.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, OK, put it at the bottom.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, It's not working under the old mongoose (3.8.28) either. I thought I had that tested already. Sorry for the confusion. Still not certain why it is filtering out all my data, it appears to be a valid schema to me. I'll keep investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was really simple. Can't believe I missed it. But I'll keep my question here; so if someone else makes a dumb mistake maybe this question will help.

I forgot to add

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

in the header. Apparently I didn't have my test set up correctly to begin with and I'm just noticing now.

It appears that `mongoose` changed what is returned after an `update`/`remove` operation.

Comment: Step away from the computer for a couple hours before asking a question! Let the mind clear and sleep on it!